# Apache Drill Mongo metastore

Tags: apache-drill

I   am using latest version of Drill cluster installed. I configure   mongodb as plugin storage.
I  could not find  any metadata getting  updated (like num_rows,last modified) etc etc
when i query information_schema.

Even I tried to implement mongo metastore as given in the https://drill.apache.org/docs/mongo-metastore/    but it does not seems to be working.

In Mongodb meta database and its tables not getting populated with  metadata.
Any help  is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question was addressed on the Drill slack channel, but will post an answer here anyway.

I think you are confusing a few things:

1. The Drill-MongoDB plugin is used for querying data in MongoDB from Drill.
2. Drill's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is highly dependent on the downstream system to report that information.  It could very well be that MongoDB does not report that info to Drill. If this information is available in MongoDB, we'd welcome a contribution to get that into Drill's `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.
3. Drill's metastore is used to obtain metadata about files which is then used in query planning.  To the best of my knowledge, it only works with file-based data sources.  Additionally, you have to execute an `ANALYZE TABLE` query for the metastore to be updated.  The fact that the metadata is stored in MongoDB really has nothing to do with the MongoDB plugin.

I hope this helps.